# Find out how many Milliseconds a C# program has taken to execute in your debugger

Tags: c#, performance

I need to analyze the Performance overhead of my programmed logic using C# debugger. So I need to compare two logics in my code. I dont want to install any add-ons like Analyze into my VisualStudio. I want to analyze the module by writing special functions. Do we have any such predefined functions available in C# ?
I need all the options available for testing a module for being GOOD(by good i mean it takes shortest time to execute)
FYI I use VisualStudio 2010 Professional edition.

Comment: You can't use a debugger to measure perf, it slows you program down.  Use a profiler.  You purchased the wrong license if you don't want to use add-ons, VS Prof doesn't have a profiler.

Comment: Various other profilers are available, such as RedGate ANTS. Most of these have trial versions if you want to give them a go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want to measure the time a function needs to execute, you can use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

Sample:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
CallYourFunction();
stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Answer (score 3):

The usual tool for this job is the profiler. If you have the Ultimate or Premium edition of Visual Studio 2010, you can use the built-in profiler by following these instructions: [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx).

To simply measure time accurately in a .NET application, you can use [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

```
// you usually need a lot of iterations to get a stable and accurate measurement
int iterations = 10000;
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// It is important to do as little as possible between starting the
// stopwatch and calling your function. If you need to allocate memory
// or do any startup actions, do them before you start.
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
{
    YourFunction();
}

// Similarly, don't do anything more after your code is done, just get
// the elapsed time immediately.
TimeSpan totalDuration = stopwatch.Elapsed;
TimeSpan durationForEachIteration =
    TimeSpan.FromTicks(totalDuration.Ticks / iterations);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of **StopWatch** class avaialble in **System.Diagnostics** namesapce

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); 
stopWatch.Start(); 
//instead of this there is line of code that you are going to execute
 Thread.Sleep(10000); 
 stopWatch.Stop(); 
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value. 
 TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed; string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

Full Post : [Get time of Code Execution Using StopWatch](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/07/during-development-of.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to measure the time of execution you could use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

Generally you can benefit from everything in [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function like this

```
    CalculateTime()
    {
      //create timer
      Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
      //start measuring time
      sw.Start();
      //your logic you want to measure
      //stop recording time
      sw.Stop();

      //you can calculate result using sw.ElapsedTicks;
    }
```